# Website with splash page with user selection

Tags: website-design, usability, splash-screen

I'm designing a website that has two distinct audiences. My current idea is to have a splash page with a selection stating to which audience the person belongs to, then it would redirect to the appropriate website content.

From what I've read online splash pages are looked down upon, as an unnecessary additional step for users, and might introduce SEO issues. What would be a better alternative to having a splash page in this case?

Comment: Who are the two groups of users?  Are they really distinct groups (no one is both)?  Are the two groups roughly the same size?

Comment: It's patients and doctors. Yes, no one would be both in our scenario. About the size, doctors would be the larger size group.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a splash screen; instead, make the choice between patients and doctors clear in the navigation on the main page.  If you display **Doctors** and **Patients** prominently, with some subheadings under each, it will allow site visitors to navigate your site more quickly and conveniently.

As for what other content you display on the main page, there are a few options:

- Default to content relevant to the larger group.
- Display general content that would apply to both.
- Display a mixture of content relevant to the two groups.

There is no one answer; it depends on the specifics of your site, really.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer, a page that goes directly to the Doctor's portion of the website would probably be the best solution, with clear navigation at the top.